# Npgsql connection string with Entity Framework core

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, npgsql

I'm using Npgsql with EF core to establish a connection to PostgreSQL for a demo console application. But I'm getting an exception 'Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0'. I think this because of some issue with the connectionstring. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Exception][image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do fine:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(@"Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=dbname;User Id=Id;Password=password");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a link to the documentation?